# C# call function based on subType of object

Tags: c#, oop

I am confused by C# right now.

I have a bunch of classes, say A, B, and C, which all derive from class "Parent".  I have a function which takes an argument of type Parent, and depending on which child class the object it is called with is, I want it to call a different method.

Currently, I am thinking using a dictionary mapping types to delegates, but that seems silly, though it is all I can come up with at the moment.

The problem is that when I am in the function, I only know that it is of type Parent, and I can use GetType to get which child class I have, which would allow the dictionary.  Otherwise I would probably use function overloading.

Really typecasting seems like the best method, allowing me to use function overloading, which would be much less verbose, but I don't know how I could do it or if it would work at all.

Any reccomendations?

Comment: Unfortunatley, I have no control over the objects in question, so I cannot add methods to them.  Probably that would be the right way.
I looked into the Dictionary of delegates, but it is leaving a lot of boilerplate type conversion code.  So I asked a question about calling overloaded functions with Typecasting Generics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overloading is the correct way

```
public void DoWork(Parent obj)
{
   if(obj is A)
     Foo((A)obj);

   else if(obj is B)
     Foo((B)obj);

   else
    Foo(obj);
}

public void Foo(Parent obj)
{
  //Do something for parent
}

public void Foo(A obj)
{
  //Do something for A
}

public void Foo(B obj)
{
  //Do something for B
}
```

or if you don't want to explicitly cast the object for each type you could use reflection like this:

```
Bar methodObject = new Bar();
MethodInfo method = methodObject.GetType().GetMethod(
            "Foo", new Type[] { obj.GetType()});

method.Invoke(methodObject, new object[]{obj});
```

Answer (score 7):

Do the methods all share the same signature? If so, make it a virtual (potentially abstract) method in the parent class:

```
using System;

public abstract class Parent
{
    public abstract void DoSomething();
}

public class A : Parent
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A.DoSomething()");
    }
}

public class B : Parent
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B.DoSomething()");
    }
}

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Parent a = new A();
        Parent b = new B();
        a.DoSomething();
        b.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

If this isn't suitable then [double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) *may* be suitable, but I'd really need to know more about the situation... it could be that changing some part of the existing design would work better.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a perfect use for the visitor pattern, if you can't add a virtual method to Parent, and override in A,B and C

Comment: Sure, if double dispatch is needed, but it's not clear whether it is.  I'm guessing not.

Comment: I'm not suggesting double dispatch.  Did you intend to comment on John Skeet's post?

Comment: The visitor pattern is double dispatch.

Answer (score 0):

Is the name of the method different?  Or is it a different implementation of the same method?

If the name of the method is the same, you can use override.  Additionally, if there will only ever be a child method, the parent method should be marked abstract.

EDIT: with code...

```
public abstract class parentClass
{
    //...other stuff...
    protected abstract void doSomething(); //or use virtual instead of abstract and give the method a body
}

public class childClass : parentClass
{
    //...other stuff...
    protected override void doSomething()
    {
       //...do something
    }
}
```